# Remove duplicate items in object but not all of it

Tags: powershell

How can I remove duplicates before exporting to a csv?

```
foreach ($group in $ADGroups) {
        $ADResult += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ADGroup = $group.name
            ADuser  = $user.name
        }
        #Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Members $UserInfo.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
        $group = $null
    }
```

In the above bit of code the result comes out like

```
aduser | adgroup
x      | a  
x      | s
x      | v
```

The `aduser` is the same for each group. How can I post the user once
so it comes out like the following without the duplicate user?

```
aduser | adgroup
x      | a  
       | s
       | v
```

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: I think visually it looks better and I find the idea interesting

Comment: Export to CSV, import into a spreadsheet, then delete what you don't want.

Comment: Although it might "look better", you will lose a lot of functionality within the data. You will no longer be able to filter or sort properly. If you really want to experience the full pleasure of having one entry on the left and several entries on the right, then maybe try converting to an XML or Json file ;)

Comment: Agree - doing this will break a lot of useful ways of analyzing the data. Better to keep the raw data as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the output as you requested. You'll lose the ability to sort and filter if you plan to work with the output data in Excel but it's your choice.

```
#Users Group Membership
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter *
$groupMembership = foreach ($group in $ADGroups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user'  }
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ADuser  = $member.name
            ADGroup = $group.name
        }
    }
}

#Get Unique Users
$usersUnique = $groupMembership | Select-Object -Property ADuser -Unique | Sort-Object -Property ADuser
#Loop each Unique user and add a new NoteProperty ADuser2. This will be populated with ADuser if its the first occurrence, else blank.
$results = foreach ($user in $usersUnique) {
    $firstOccurrence = $true
    $userMembership = $groupMembership | Where-Object { $_.ADuser -eq $user.ADuser } | Sort-Object -Property ADGroup
    foreach ($membership in $userMembership) {
        if ($firstOccurrence) {
            $membership | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ADuser2 -Value $user.ADuser -PassThru
            $firstOccurrence = $false
        }
        else {
            $membership | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ADuser2 -Value "" -PassThru
        }
    }
}
#Export to CSV
$results | Sort-Object -Property ADuser, ADGroup | Select-Object ADuser2, ADGroup | Export-Csv -Path C:\support\user-group_membership_report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
$i = 0
foreach ($group in $ADGroups) {
    if($i -eq 0){
        $ADResult += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ADGroup = $group.name
            ADuser  = $user.name
        }
        $i = 1
    }
    else {
        $ADResult += [PSCustomObject]@{
            ADGroup = $group.name
            ADuser  = ""
        } 
    }
}
```